# PHP MSQL FORM Query Won't Connect

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hey guys I've been trying to do a code where I submit a form from a PHP Order Page so that it can update the MySQL Database with the required information

I've got the Order PHP Code Here:

```
<form action="http://zim.cs.uow.edu.au/~ga420/order.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <th>Shirts</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH01" />
            <label for="rd1">Obey T-Shirt: $9.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH02" />
            <label for="rd1">Obey Professor: $9.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH03" />
            <label for="rd1">Hustle T-Shirt: $9.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH04" />
            <label for="rd1">Hip-Hop Support: $9.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH05" />
            <label for="rd1">90's Shirt: $9.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH06" />
            <label for="rd1">DOPE Shirt: $9.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="qty" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SO1" />
            <label for="rd1">Shoe - Red Lace: $19.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SO2" />
            <label for="rd1">Shoe - Red High Top: $19.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SO3" />
            <label for="rd1">Shoe - White: $19.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SO4" />
            <label for="rd1">Shoe - Black: $19.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SO5" />
            <label for="rd1">Shoe - Black High Top: $19.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SO6" />
            <label for="rd1">Red Basketball: $19.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SN1" />
            <label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SN2" />
            <label for="rd1">Snapback: $29.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SN3" />
            <label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SN4" />
            <label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SN5" />
            <label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="SN6" />
            <label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2" />
            <br/>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $conn = mysql_connect('url','username','password');
    if (!$con){
        die("Could Not Connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("db",$conn);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Order_Information(Order_ID,Order_Items,Order_Quantity) VALUES (null,$_POST[items]','$_POST[qty]')";

    mysql_query($sql, $con);

mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

Obviously my username and password I won't display but when I hit the submit button it says that it cannot connect.

You can try the form yourself on this website:
http://zim.cs.uow.edu.au/~ga420/order.php

How come it is saying that I can't connect when clearly I have been putting the right details in.

Can anyone help? this has been stressing me out :'(

Your help is appreciated greatly!!

Comment: nice and easy sql inject that thing ;)

Comment: You wrote `$conn = mysql_connect('zim.cs.uow.edu.au','username','password');` - $conn with 2 "n"

Comment: @Joe the mysql host passed to mysql_connect has port 3306 closed (tested with nmap).

Comment: @user1618490 are you sure your php code can connect to port 3306 of the specified mysql host ? Have you tried passing `'localhost'` to `mysql_connect()` ?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani - I think you mean `user1618490`, I just tried to make the code a little more readable :)

Comment: One more small notice: `VALUES (null,$_POST[items]','$_POST[qty]')";` - re-check the `'`

Comment: @Joe I think your edit is good, but using `'url'` as `mysql_connect()` first argument is obviously wrong, IMHO. I suppose you edited away the real hostname for security reasons.

Comment: @Sergio I think you can get easy points if you write about that typos in a proper answer ;-)

Comment: @Joe Forget about my comment, `'url'` is clear enough... Sorry for the noise :-)

Comment: The only thing is now is that it will not update the qty value for my table

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize all your inputs/quantities if you will have the same name "qty" in all fields. I will update my answer later if you do t get answer about this.

You had also small bugs on your code, notice this:

`VALUES (null,'$_POST[items]','$_POST[qty]')";` - you were missing `'` before $_POST[items]

`$conn = mysql_connect('zim.cs.uow.edu.au','username','password');` - $conn with 2 "n"

So, a corrected version would be:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$con = mysql_connect('url','username','password');
if (!$con){
    die("Could Not Connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db",$con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Order_Information(Order_ID,Order_Items,Order_Quantity) VALUES (null,'$_POST[items]','$_POST[qty]')";

mysql_query($sql, $con);

mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense in here mysql_select_db("db",$conn); Your first connection variable is $con. So, why don't you use this $conn?

Comment: @Thiha i just forgot that one, corrected my answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this. You did some mistake on $conn and $con. Then, `'$_POST[items]','$_POST[qty]'` in query.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$conn = mysql_connect('url','username','password');
if (!$conn){
    die("Could Not Connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db",$conn);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Order_Information(Order_ID,Order_Items,Order_Quantity) VALUES      (null,'$_POST[items]','$_POST[qty]')";

mysql_query($sql, $conn);

mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Hope this help