# Issue with PHP Updating MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm having issues with the form below, whenever i click on an item it catches the item and updates on the mySQL table, it only displays 1 item(how do i make it display all the items that i have checked?).

Also when i put in a quantity in it doesn't update on the mySQL table and it just says 0 when i've put multiple quantities of each item.

Are you guys able to help if that's ok?

```
<tr>
<th>Shirts</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr>

<tr>

<td>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH01" /><label for="rd1">Obey T-Shirt: $9.99</label></div> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH02" /><label for="rd1">Obey Professor: $9.99</label></div> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH03" /><label for="rd1">Hustle T-Shirt: $9.99</label></div> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH04" /><label for="rd1">Hip-Hop Support: $9.99</label></div> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH05" /><label for="rd1">90's Shirt: $9.99</label></div> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH06" /><label for="rd1">DOPE Shirt: $9.99</label></div> <br />
        <br />
</td>

<td> 
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="qty" size ="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <br />

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SO1" /><label for="rd1">Shoe - Red Lace: $19.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SO2" /><label for="rd1">Shoe - Red High Top: $19.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SO3" /><label for="rd1">Shoe - White: $19.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SO4" /><label for="rd1">Shoe - Black: $19.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SO5" /><label for="rd1">Shoe - Black High Top: $19.99</label></div><br /> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SO6" /> <label for="rd1">Red Basketball: $19.99</label></div><br />
        <br />
    </td>

    <td> 
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" size ="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="2"/><br/>
        <br />

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SN1" /> <label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SN2" /><label for="rd1">Snapback: $29.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SN3" /><label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SN4" /><label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SN5" /><label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label></div><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SN6" /><label for="rd1">Snapback Bullets: $29.99</label></div><br />
        <br />
    </td>
<td> 
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="qty" size ="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty" size="2"/><br/>
        <br />

</td>   
</tr>

</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$con = mysql_connect('$localhost','$url','$pass');
if (!$con)
{
die("Could Not Connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("$username",$con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Order_Information(Order_ID,Order_Items,Order_Quantity) VALUES (null,'$_POST[items]','$_POST[qty]')";

mysql_query($sql,$con);

mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: What error you are getting after executing the query?

Comment: You can have a look at my website:

http://zim.cs.uow.edu.au/~ga420/order.php

The order form works, but when updating the quantity of the order it doesn't update

Comment: checkbox values are either on or nothing. first you need to name your `text` boxes to match the item names because otherwise there will be no way to reference which checkbox belongs to which qty.  then also name your checkbox using VALUE as the name

Comment: @DevZer0 so you reckon i should give the qty another name? 
http://zim.cs.uow.edu.au/~ga420/order.php this is the site i'm trying to update

Comment: @user1618490 it's much easier that way. i will post a short answer for you in a min

Comment: Next time avoid asking the same question in the same day... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230756/php-msql-form-query-wont-connect

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is update in a foreach loop so that you are inserting one row for each checked item and secondly you need to relate the quantity fields to those items by using an array.

Change your Quantity field names to an array including the code for the items:

```
<input type="text" name="qty['SO1']" size ="2"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="qty['SO2']" size="2"/><br/>
etc ...
```

Then in your PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item) {
  foreach($_POST['qty'] as $key => $value) {
    $quantity = 0;
    if ($key == $item) {
      $quantity = $value;
    }
  }
$sql = "INSERT INTO Order_Information(Order_Items,Order_Quantity) VALUES ('$item', '$quantity')";
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="SH01" />
<input type="text" name="qty_SH01" ..../>
```

PHP

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
   if (!preg_match("/^SH/", $key)) continue;

   $qty = $_POST['qty_' . $key];

   $sql = "INSERT INTO Order_Information(Order_Items,Order_Quantity) VALUES ('$key', '$qty')";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. When using the `$_POST[items]`, you forgot about the apostrophes - `$_POST['items']`.
2. To get all checked checkboxes, you need a loop:

   ```
   if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
   {
       foreach($_POST['items'] as $item)
       {
           ....
       }
   }
   ```